# Counting All Character Occurrences in a Text File in C

Tags: c, frequency

I'm trying to count all the character occurrences in a text file, but the output I get is the occurrence output line by line.

I.e.,

Text file:

```
aaaaAAA
a
a
```

Output for the file above

```
O caracter 'a' aparece 4 vez(es)
O caracter 'a' aparece 1 vez(es)
O caracter 'a' aparece 1 vez(es)
```

Translation: the character 'a' appears 4 time(s)

What I want is this:

```
O caracter 'a' aparece 6 vez(es)
O caracter 'A' aparece 3 vez(es)
```

Code:

```
 int strcountc(char *text, char c){
    int i, n=0;
    for(i=0; text[i]!='\0'; i++)
        if(text[i]==c)
            n++;
    return n;
}

int main(void)
{
  FILE *ficheiro1;
  char texto_str[3000];


  ficheiro1 = fopen("encrypted_file.txt", "r");


  while(fgets(texto_str, 3000, ficheiro1) != NULL)

printf("O caracter 'a' aparece %d vez(es)\n", strcountc(texto_str,'a' ));




  fclose(ficheiro1);
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: `size_t counter[256] = {0};` .. `strcountc(texto_str, counter);`.. print result.

Comment: Included output, expected output, and translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of fgets() . It considers until it encounters a newline character. you are reading line by line. Either you can use static int n = 0; or do

```
int k = 0;

ficheiro1 = fopen("encrypted_file.txt", "r");


 while(fgets(texto_str, 3000, ficheiro1) != NULL)
    {
            k = k +strcountc(texto_str,'a' );
    }

    printf("no of char\t %d", k);
```

Comment: In your code `k` is uninitialized which will lead to undefined behavior

Comment: @Gopi think now it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration you set value of `n` to `0` in the function call which will not give you the count of number of characters.

You should make it

```
static int n=0;
```

if you want to keep count of all occurrences of `a` in your file.